# How to access object value properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, sweetalert

I have checked a value of an object by console log like this:

```
if (isConfirm) {
   console.log(isConfirm); // first condition
}else{
   console.log(isConfirm); // second condition
}
```

And the *first condition* shows the object like this:

```
{value: true}
value: true
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

first condition result

[image]

And the *second condition* shows the object like this:

```
{dismiss: "cancel"}
dismiss: "cancel"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

2nd condition result

[image]

So the question is, how can I properly access value of `isConfirm` object properly at each condition?

I tried accessing the first condition value like this:

```
if (isConfirm === true) {
    console.log("RETURNS TRUE");
}
```

But this is wrong since `RETURNS TRUE` does not print out at Console.

So what is proper way of accessing object value in this case?

Comment: Please do not post images in question, please paste the actual logs instead.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I just added it, please check it out

Comment: added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `isConfirm` object in the first condition is returning a different object then it is returning in the second condition:

This is what you need to do :

```
if(isConfirm.value !== undefind && isConfirm.value === true ) {
  console.log("RETURNS TRUE")
}
```

the first condition : `isConfirm.value !== undefined` checks that alteast the `value` object exists in the first condition, because in the second condition, it doesn't exist at all

and the next condition would be to check if it's true.

An optimized way is :

`if( isConfirm.value )`

that does the above two checks in one go.

Answer (score 1):

you can not directly use operation on value inside the object. Need to access the inside value and as per your statement you can access the value using `isConfirm.value` instead of `isconfirm` and make if...else condition on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
swal({
              title: "Are you sure?",
              text: "You want to delete this file!",
              icon: "warning",
              buttons: [
                'No, cancel it!',
                'Yes, I am sure!'
              ],
              dangerMode: true,
            }).then(function(isConfirm) {
              if (isConfirm) {
                swal({
                  title: 'Deleted!',
                  text: 'Candidates are successfully Deleted!',
                  icon: 'success'
                }).then(function() {
                  form.submit();
                });
              } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
              }
            });
```